# Is there any way to use sipjs or other method to get rtcp packets？

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtp, rtcp, sipjs

I use sip.js to mkae a webrtc test. And I wang to get some information from rtcp.

I tried to use getStatus() API,but I want the rtcp packet form the other side.Because getStatus() can not calculate the out-bound rtp packt lost and jitter. Is there any way to get the message?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.